# Castle Active Record NHibernate Same Session 2 versions of the same object

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord, transactionscope

I have a Car in DB where Model field is "Ferrari"

```
using (new TransactionScope())
{
    var car = Find(1);
    car.Model = "Ferrari Plus";

    // i need the old Car value to make a comparison
    var car2 = Find(1);

    // i need here the db Car record, instead i have the cached Nhibernate value
    if (car2.Model == 'Ferrari") 
        // do something
}
```

i modified the code in this way

```
using (new TransactionScope())
{
    var car = Find(1);
    car.Model = "Ferrari Plus";

    // i need the old Car value to make a comparison
    using (new TransactionScope())
    {
        var car2 = Find(1);
        // i got  the db value buuuuuuut
        // if i save because i need to save the modific Car i got an error
        if (car2.Model == 'Ferrari") 
            car.Save(); // ERROR: 2 objects with the same id exists
    }

}
```

how can i avoid this problem?
How can i get 2 versions of the same object into the same NHibernate Session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the base principles of nhibernate is to not have 2 objects that are the same in the same session.  What you are asking cannot be done as far as I know.

#### Possible Solution 1

You could query `car` in one session close the session.  Query `car2` in another session and do your compare against the two objects.  Update `car2` with `car`'s properties.

#### Possible Solution 2

Do the same as above except don't copy the values from `car` to `car2`.  Instead you would open another session and do a `session.Update(car);`

#### Possible Solution 3

You could do is to create a copy of the original or create a dto.  When you do your comparison compare the persistent instance (changed copy) to the copy/dto.

Answer (score 0):

You can Evict() an object and tell ActiveRecord / NHibernate to no longer track this Object. But you need to do this before you start changing it. So your code should look like this:

```
// i need the old Car value to make a comparison
var car2 = Find(1);
ActiveRecordMediator.Evict(car2); //Tell AR to no longer track this object

var car = Find(1);  // now returns a new fresh version from the database
car.Model = "Ferrari Plus";

if (car2.Model == 'Ferrari") 
    // do something
```

Take a Look at this [Active Record Lifecycle Diagram](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/lifecycle.html).